# fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD' error while updating pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is the line I have used in my pod file
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

previously it was
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'

I tried the following

- pod install
- pod update &
- pod update 'SDWebImage'

All resulted to the following screen and its not getting completed, I have waited more than 30 minutes. Still no improvements.

[image]

I don't know how to overcome this issue. But I need to update the pod anyhow. Does anyone aware of this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Its fine for me, maybe try delete the pod folder and install again, also try `pod cache clean SDWebImage`, if not works then do the following to reinstall the master repo:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Comment: I tried the above but after using "pod setup" I got this error "RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -36". and when I reverted the changes and tried again from "pod repo remove master" it showed "[!] repo master does not exist"

Comment: then just run `pod setup`

Comment: I reset all the changes and again tried just "pod setup" alone as you said, but I the terminal stopped in this line "Setting up CocoaPods master repo" for more than 20 minutes and not file has been updated while I see in the sourcetree. I don't understand why this happens, I was using pod for long time but now I got stuck here.

Comment: It's normal, the repo is around 400-500mb to download, so yeah, depends on the network it might take long, git server is bad also

Comment: Thank you, I just used "pod setup" and waited for around 30 minutes and then it got completed.